# My Chrome Extension's popup window is too large for a small screen. How to address this?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do not specifically set the height for the *popup window* for my Google Chrome Extension. It automatically shows the vertical scrollbar when its dynamically generated content reaches about 600px in height. This seems to work fine on my desktop computer.

But I just happened to test my extension on a screen with a high DPI setting (i.e. 150%), and when I clicked my extension's badge icon the popup window opened up past the display height, all the way off the screen, without showing the vertical scroll bar.

Is there any way to address this?

**EDIT**: My CSS for the popup page itself is just this:

```
html,body{
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    min-width: 24em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

**EDIT**: I was able to make a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Comment: Remove the `overflow:hidden;` declaration from your stylesheet, change it to `overflow:auto;`. This is just my guess without seeing your code, you should really create a minimal example and include its code in your question...

Comment: @RobW: I do not use `overflow`. Still I tried adding `overflow:auto;` as you suggested and besides adding an ugly horizontal scrollbar it didn't help.

Comment: The code in your question is not enough to demonstrate the issue. Have you tried adding `html,body{height:100%;}`?

Comment: @RobW: No. It didn't help. See screenshot above. This time it added a vertical scrollbar when it was not needed.

Comment: Also add `margin:0;` to body. By default is is something like 8px, so `100% height + 16px padding` is bigger than the 100% height, which causes the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: I would say it's a bug. The popup is supposed to be constrained to a reasonable size, and it's quite possible that those constraints did not take DPI into account. File a bug under https://crbug.com ?

Comment: @Xan: Thank you for admitting it being a bug. From my short experience dealing with Chrome, I can tell that it's poorly designed dealing with higher screen DPIs.

Comment: @c00000fd Admitting? I have no connection to Chrome devs. It's just an educated guess based on the same observation.

Comment: @Xan: What I meant to say is that you're not telling me that there's something wrong with my popup window/css.

Comment: I confirm this issue. Incorrect pixel counting with zoomed DPI. Did you file a bug? You may be able to work around this bug using javascript and `availHeight`, but that won't account for the top position of the window.

Comment: @ScottF: No. I didn't file it. Do you want to do it instead? If so, post a link here.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it is just hardcoded, so no device pixel counting or screen bottom calculations in the first place. I think it was more complicated in the past, but I'm fine with hardcoded 600 web-px personally.

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: @Community: It's been a while, but I don't think so.

Comment: i settled with setting the height of both html and body to a fixed smaller px and set both their overflow-y to scroll. of course this means that its small to all screens now.

Comment: @Community: yeah, I don't think I went that route. You're technically penalizing the majority of the users.